# Procmail: Forward incomming message, and send notify to another e-mail adress

Tags: procmail

If there is an incomming e-mail from some specified e-mail adresses, I want to forward that e-mail to on e-mail address, and send a notification to another one.

I have tried using both formail and running bash script directly from procmail, but I can not get it to work.

The e-mail should be forwarded unaltered, but the notification e-mail should just contain the senders e-mail address and subject, if possible (not required).

Here is my latest attempt at a procmail-recipe:

```
:0
* ! ^From:.*email@example.org
* ! ^From:.*support@example.com
* ! ^From:.*santa@northpole.no
{ }
:0 E
{
  :0 c
  ! mail@mycompany.com

  :0 h
  | /usr/local/bin/notify_mail.sh $FROM $SUBJECT
}
```

My `notify_mail.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Hi,\n\nNew e-mail has arrived:\n\nFROM: $1\nSUBJECT $2" | mail -s "$2" me@mycompany.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should work as such, but you are not populating the `FROM` and `SUBJECT` variables, and you should generally [quote your shell variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Try this:

```
0
* ! ^From:.*email@example\.org
* ! ^From:.*support@example\.com
* ! ^From:.*santa@northpole\.no
{ }
:0 E
{
  :0 c
  ! mail@mycompany.com

  FROM=`formail -rtzxTo:`
  SUBJECT=`formail -zxSubject:`
  :0 h
  | /usr/local/bin/notify_mail.sh "$FROM" "$SUBJECT"
}
```

The `formail -rtzxTo:` idiom is slightly tricky, and is explained e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890026/874188

Notice also the backslashes before the literal dots in the regexes.

The script should probably prefer `printf` over `echo -e`. There is nothing Bash-specific here, so I also took the liberty to change the shebang.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
printf "Hi,\n\nNew e-mail has arrived:\n\nFROM: %s\nSUBJECT %s\n" "$1" "$2" |
mail -s "$2" me@mycompany.com
```

Comment: Since you are piping the headers to the script anyway, you could also refactor it to extract the information from those headers. I didn't go there because you might have other uses for this script which depend on the current behavior.